# Calculate the general solution of this ODE

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

> Consider the linear ODE system:
>
> $\dot x = \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & -1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 2 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}x, x(t_0)=x_0 $
>
> (i) Calculate the general solution
>
> (ii) Calculate the particular solution when $x(0)=(0,0,1)^T$
>
> (iii) Calculate the restriction of the dynamics to the unstable subspace $E^u$.

I believe I have the general solution for (i) with

$e^{tA}=e^t\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -t & t-t^2 \\
0 & 1 & 2t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

(my working is quite long but I could add it if necessary)

so the general solution would be

$x(t)= e^t\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -t & t-t^2 \\
0 & 1 & 2t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}x(0)$?

for (ii) I replaced x(0) with the conditions to get:

$x(t)= e^t\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -t & t-t^2 \\
0 & 1 & 2t \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
0  \\
0 \\
 1
\end{pmatrix}=e^t\begin{pmatrix} 
t-t^2  \\
2t \\
 1
\end{pmatrix}$?

but I'm really not sure where to go from here, any help?

Comment: You say that your working to find the general solution is long. If you decompose the coefficient matrix into the sum of the identity and a nilpotent matrix, you can compute its exponential directly and fairly easily, without having to find any generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You’ve already computed both the general and particular solutions, contrary to the title of the question.